# Apply same function to several Dataframes - R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, lapply

I'm currently working with 8 databases with the same structure, what I would like to know is how to apply the same steps and modifications to all the bases at the same time.

I know that with the **lapply** function and passing the databases to a list it is possible to do but I can not specify it.

The steps I need to perform are as follows:

```
df1$EMAIL <- str_to_lower(df1$EMAIL)
df2$EMAIL <- str_to_lower(df2$EMAIL)
dfn$EMAIL <- str_to_lower(dfn$EMAIL)
df8$EMAIL <- str_to_lower(df8$EMAIL)

d1$EMAIL <- stri_trans_general(d1$EMAIL,"Latin-ASCII") 
d2$EMAIL <- stri_trans_general(d2$EMAIL,"Latin-ASCII")
dn$EMAIL <- stri_trans_general(dn$EMAIL,"Latin-ASCII")
d8$EMAIL <- stri_trans_general(d8$EMAIL,"Latin-ASCII")

df1$CATEGORY <- str_to_Title(df1$CATEGORY)
df2$CATEGORY <- str_to_Title(df2$CATEGORY)
dfn$CATEGORY <- str_to_Title(dfn$CATEGORY)
df8$CATEGORY <- str_to_Title(df8$CATEGORY)

df1_e <- select(df1, EMAIL, CATEGORY, COMPANY)
df2_e <- select(df2, EMAIL, CATEGORY, COMPANY)
dfn_e <- select(dfn, EMAIL, CATEGORY, COMPANY)
df8_e <- select(df8, EMAIL, CATEGORY, COMPANY)

EMAILS <- bind_rows(df1_e, df2_e, dfn_e, dfn_8)%>%unique(EMAIL)
```

They are simple steps that do not require much time to perform one by one. But I would like to learn how to be more efficient and save space and time in the script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply create a function that receives a data frame as input, runs all needed processes on that *one* data frame, and outputs a cleaned data frame. Then call function in `lapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution as you have already identified is to put the dataframes in a list and use `lapply`/`map` on each dataframe.

Here's a solution using `map_df` from `purrr`.  If the dataframe are called as `df1`, `df2`... `df8` then you can use `mget` to create a list of dataframes. I have also created an `id` variable which will give the dataframe name for each row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

EMAILS <- map_df(mget(paste0('df', 1:8)), function(x) {
  x %>%
    transmute(EMAIL = str_to_lower(EMAIL) %>% stri_trans_general("Latin-ASCII"), 
              CATEGORY = str_to_title(CATEGORY), 
              COMPANY)
}, .id = 'id') %>% distinct(EMAIL, .keep_all = TRUE)
```